# What is the most efficient way to split an array of numbers, such that sum of each subset is as close to a target as possible, without exceeding it?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, partitioning, data-partitioning

I am faced with this optimization challenge:

Take for example the array, `[1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 6, 2, 1, 6, 7, 4, 2]`
I want to split this into multiple sub-arrays, such that their sums are as close to a target sum. Say, 7.
The only condition I have is the sums cannot be more that the target sum.

Using a greedy approach, I can split them as
`[1, 2, 4], [3, 3, 1], [6], [2, 4], [6], [7], [2]`
The subset sums are 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7 and 2.

Another approach I tried is as follows:

1. Sort the array, in reverse.
2. Set up a running total initialized to 0, and an empty subset.
3. If the list is empty, proceed to Step 6.
4. Going down the list, pick the first number, which when added to the running total does not exceed the target sum. If no such element is found, proceed to Step 6, else proceed to Step 5.
5. Remove this element from the list, add it to the subset, and update running total. Repeat from step 3.
6. Print the current subset, clear the running total and subset. If the list isn't empty, repeat from Step 3. Else proceed to Step 7.
7. You're done!

This approach produced the following split:
`[7], [6, 1], [6, 1], [4, 3], [4, 3], [2, 2, 2]`

The subset sum was much more even: 7, 7, 7, 7, 7 and 6.

Is this the best strategy?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: _their sums are as close to a target sum_ is very unclear. Consider `[5, 3, 2]`. Is `[5,2], [3]` better than `[5], [3,2]`, or worse, or equivalent?

Comment: I want to maximize the subsets that sum to target sum. In this case, `[5, 2], [3]` is preferred.

Comment: @HariKrishnan [Were the answers helpful?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the terms "subset" and "sub-array" carefully. What you are looking for is "subset".

The best strategy here would be to write the recursive solution that tries each possibility of forming a subset so that the sum remains <= maximum allowed sum.

If you carefully understand what the recursion does, you'll understand that some sub-problems are being solved again and again. So, you can (memoize) store the solutions to the sub-problems and re-use them. Thus, reading about dynamic programming will help you.

Comment: If I have hundreds of elements in my array, "every possible subset" will become infeasible to compute, and further more, most of them would be pretty bad. It will consider low value single element subsets, as they are technically valid, but that will most definitely not work. I don't see how that might be the best approach here?

Comment: 'low value single element subsets' won't be considered because we keep filling up the same subset to the maximum value possible that doesn't cross the maximum allowed sum.

Comment: Because of hundreds of elements, we need to go for dynamic programming. Only recursive solution won't suffice.

Comment: If [1, 2, 3] is the array and max allowed sum is 3, then don't take subset as [1]. Take [1, 2] because that still keeps the subset sum below or equal to max allowed sum.

Comment: Okay, so if I form every possible subset, while maximizing my sum, will it not repeat elements across two subsets? If you can, can you algorithmically describe your solution?

Comment: To make sure that you don't pick the same element in different subsets, you can simply maintain a boolean visited array. When an element picked in a subset, mark it as visited. While picking a new element, take care that the element is not marked as visited

Comment: You can take the code from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-to-find-all-subsets/) for a head-start.